# Change a list into a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to change a list in the format `[["bill", 21], ["kevin", 42], ["gail",20]]` into a dictionary in the format `{"bill":21, "kevin":42, "gail":20}`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [2]: l = [['bill', 21], ['kevin', 42], ['gail',20]]

In [3]: d = dict(l)
In [4]: d
Out[4]: {'gail': 20, 'bill': 21, 'kevin': 42}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still have one more problem - what you did has worked but as I am importing my list from a file it is putting in the number as a string [['bill', '21'], ['kevin', '42'], ]. So when I change to dictionary I'm getting {'bill':'21', 'kevin':'42, 'gail':'20'} can you think of a way to change the '21' key value into a straight 21 integer?

Comment: @user3864194 you can make second list with correct values, which you input into dict(), e.g. `l2 = [[v[0],float(v[1])] for v in l]`

Answer (score 3):

The `dict()` constructor takes an iterable of 2-sized iterables. As such, you could simply call `dict` on your list:

```
In [11]: L = [['bill', 21], ['kevin', 42], ['gail',20]]

In [12]: dict(L)
Out[12]: {'bill': 21, 'kevin': 42, 'gail': 20}
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert **dictionary-values** to **integers** use this code:

```
>>> text=[["bill", '21'], ["kevin", '42'], ["gail",'20']]
>>> dict([[i,int(j)] for i,j in text])
{'bill': 21, 'kevin': 42, 'gail': 20}
```